# Perl collecting xml snippets from log with specific contents

Tags: perl, search

I have a script copied from another stackoverflow question, but it seems to replace the content of the variable, could someone point me to the error? If i remove the if check for the ">OK<" it prints the whole xml to a file, if i put the if back it only prints the line containing the ">OK<", why is the $xml variable modified by the =~?

```
# Example usage:
# perl script.pl data.xml RootTag > RootTag.xml

use strict;
use warnings;

my $tag = pop;

while (<>){
  if ( s/.*(<$tag>)/$1/ .. s/(<(\/)$tag>).*/$1/ ) {
    my $xml = $_;
    if ($xml =~ m/>OK</) {
        print "$xml";
    }
  }
}
```

An example of a input file could be

```
reioirioree
brebreberbre
rbebrbebre
<test>
<id>1</id>
<status>OK</status>
</test>
bbrtbtrbt
rtbtrb
<test>
<id>2</id>
<status>KO</status>
</test>
brtoibjtrbi
bebbetreb
<test>
<id>3</id>
<status>OK</status>
</test>
dfbreberbreb
berbrebre
```

In this case if we user "test" as parameter, i would like following output

```
<test>
<id>1</id>
<status>OK</status>
</test>
<test>
<id>3</id>
<status>OK</status>
</test>
```

Comment: `=~ m` doesn't modify a variable, but returns true or false.

Comment: `$xml` contains the current line. It is printed only when it contains `>OK<`, if you remove the test, the script prints all the lines.

Comment: Sample data would be useful. Because the answer here is probably don't use regex for XML parsing. But I can't give you a better solution without your data.

Comment: @choroba If i remove the check on OK and leave the print statement it prints the whole xml snippet, otherwise it prints only the line containing the OK, where is the $xml variable modified then?

Comment: The input goes into `$_`.  Then that _is modified_ in the range with `if`s, since `s/` by default works on `$_`.  So it's anyone's guess what `$xml` then gets, being assigned `$_`. We'd need to see the data.

Comment: See, that's one reason why it's good to show input and output -- what you actually want, _now_ clear, won't be done by the posted code.  And, regardless of the mysterious behavior you say you see, which I don't (I get with your script and input exactly as expected, two lines with the `OK` phrase in them.)

Comment: @zdim It is not entirely clear what you mean with the code snipper, i've added push `@buff, $_;` instead of `my $xml = $_;` and did the check on $_ for the OK. And if there is a match i've printed @buff, but the output file is empty

Comment: That really wasn't very clear ... posted nicely instead.  Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objective is to capture the whole `tag` when it contains a specific pattern (`>OK<`).

Here is a step-by-step way which spells out details. I keep your program interface.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $tag = pop;

my ($inside_tag, $found, @buff);

while (<>)
{
    if (s/.*(<$tag>)/$1/) {
        $inside_tag = 1;
    }   
    elsif (s|(</$tag>).*|$1|) {  #/
        $inside_tag = 0;
        if ($found) { 
            print @buff, $_;
            $found = 0;
        }
        @buff = ();
    }   

    next unless $inside_tag;

    push @buff, $_; 

    $found = 1 if />OK</;
}
```

On the opening tag we set the flag that we are inside the tag. On the closing tag we unset it, and if the marker has been `$found` we print the buffer (and unset marker's flag). We clear the buffer here.

Then we skip the iteration if outside of the tag. Otherwise, add the line to the buffer and test for the marker on that line.

---

A glitch with using the range in this problem  is that we must know when we are on the closing-tag line, and would like to know the opening line as well. Then we need further tests and flip-flop isn't so clean any more. We can use the *sequence number* that the [`..` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) returns

> The value returned is either the empty string for false, or a sequence number (beginning with 1) for true. The sequence number is reset for each range encountered. The final sequence number in a range has the string `"E0"` appended to it, which doesn't affect its numeric value, but gives you something to search for if you want to exclude the endpoint. You can exclude the beginning point by waiting for the sequence number to be greater than 1.

It would go something like

```
if (my $seq = /BEG/ .. /END/) 
{
    if ($seq == 1)        {  # first line of range
        # ...
    }
    elsif ($seq =~ /EO$/) {  # last line of range
        # ...
    }
    else  { ... }            # inside
```

and I don't see that this is clearer or better than keeping the state manually.